# 「計」「全」 before ~times counter (~回)

Tags: counters

Today I heard a sentence like 「松本さんは　クライムゲームを計【けい】 4回担当しました。」. I searched Google and found that there's also 「全」 but I can't find their usage explanation. How to use 「計」 and 「全」 before counters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently 計 is short for 合計 (total, sum) while 全 is for 全部 (all, everything).

So 計 should be used with numbers which result from adding something, e.g.

> 計3万円になります
>
> The total will be 30000 yen

While 全 is for cases when there is a complete set of something:

> 全16巻(の漫画)
>
> All 16 volumes (of a manga series)

In your example sentence, it seems that Matsumoto-san was involved in four crime games in total, but presumably there were other crime games without his/her involvement.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, not only Matsumoto-san had played the game, there're some other people had played it.